# updating Apache Lucene indexed files

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am using a Apache Lucene library to create a search functionality for my website. the website is getting all its contents from Sharepoint RSSFeeds, therefore every time I have to go through all the RSSFeed urls and read the contents. to makes the search functionality faster I have created a scheduled task to do the indexing every one hour :

```
    <bean id="rssIndexerService" class="com.lloydsbanking.webmi.service.RSSIndexerService" />
<task:scheduled-tasks> <task scheduled ref="rssIndexerService" method="indexUrls" cron="0 0 * * * MON-FRI" /></task:scheduled-tasks>
```

The problem is that if I create a new contents, then the search doesnt show the new contents while the server is running and after the schduled task had been called, also if I delete an entry, it stil doesnt show the deleted entried from the index files. here is the indexing code:

```
@Service
public class RSSIndexerService extends RSSReader {

    @Autowired
    private RSSFeedUrl rssFeedUrl;

    private IndexWriter indexWriter = null;

    private String indexPath = "C:\\MI\\index";

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RSSIndexerService.class.getName());

    public void indexUrls() throws IOException {
        Date start = new Date();
        IndexWriter writer = getIndexWriter();
        log.info("Reading all the Urls in the Sharepoint");     
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> entries = rssFeedUrl.getUrlMap().entrySet().iterator();
        try {
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> mapEntry = entries.next();
                String url = mapEntry.getValue();
                SyndFeed feed = rssReader(url);
                for (Object entry : feed.getEntries()) {
                    SyndEntry syndEntry = (SyndEntry) entry;
                    SyndContent desc = syndEntry.getDescription();
                    if (desc != null) {
                        String text = desc.getValue();
                        if ("text/html".equals(desc.getType())) {
                            Document doc = new Document();
                            text = extractText(text);
                            Field fieldTitle = new StringField("title", syndEntry.getTitle(), Field.Store.YES);
                            doc.add(fieldTitle);
                            Field pathField = new StringField("path", url, Field.Store.YES);
                            doc.add(pathField);
                            doc.add(new TextField("contents", text, Field.Store.YES));

                            // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
                            writer.addDocument(doc);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        } finally {

            // closeIndexWriter();
        }
        Date end = new Date();
        log.info(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds");
    }

    public IndexWriter getIndexWriter() throws IOException {

        if (indexWriter == null) {
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);

            log.info("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath));
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);

            config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
        }
        return indexWriter;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeIndexWriter() throws IOException {
        if (indexWriter != null) {
            System.out.println("Done with indexing ...");
            indexWriter.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I know the problem might be caused by the config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);, but I dont know how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

well I came up with the idea of checking if the directory is empty before or not, if it is not then delete the previous indexes and then everytime do the indexing in the OpenMode.Create :

```
File path = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"\\index");
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(path);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);

        if (path.list() != null) {
            log.info("Delete previous indexes ...");
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(path);
        }
        config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
```

then I simple use addDocument():

```
if ("text/html".equals(desc.getType())) {
                        ...
                        // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
                        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
                    }
```